# Search per ID on access using Visual Studio 2022 VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb, oledbexception

I am trying to do a search using an ID to find the information that I need. The database is Access and the ID is an autonumber value(primary key). I am using Visual Studio 2022(visual basic) to to the search an it works if I do the search using the name but if I use the ID it give me an error. Can you help me solving this problem?

Error message:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: data type mismatch in criteria expression

This is my code:

```
Dim consulta As String 
Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter 
Dim ods As DataSet 
Dim registro As Byte 

If ComboBox2.Text <> " " Then 
    consulta = "select *from QAtracker where ID='" & TextBox55.Text & " '" 

    oda = New OleDbDataAdapter(consulta, Conexion1) 
    ods = New DataSet oda.Fill(ods, "QAtracker") 

    registro = ods.Tables("QAtracker").Rows.Count 

    If registro <> 0 Then 
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ods 

        DataGridView1.DataMember = "QAtracker" 

        TextBox55.Text = ods.Tables("QAtracker").Rows(0).Item("ID") 
        TextBox5.Text = ods.Tables("QAtracker").Rows(0).Item("Login") 
        TextBox6.Text = ods.Tables("QAtracker").Rows(0).Item("Logout") 
    else 
        MsgBox("Codigo no existe") 

        Conexion1.Close() 
    End If 
End If
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

I tried doing to search with another Value and it worked. I would love to know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The issue is your SQL code and nothing at all to do with the VB code, yet you haven't tagged the question with SQL. Also, the VS tags specifically state that they are to be used for issues with the IDE and not for issues with code that just happens to be written in VS. Put some thought into your tags and ALWAYS read teh description before using one.

Comment: As suggested in the answer, the way you're constructing your SQL code leaves a lot to be desired. It can lead to various issues, chief among them the fact that a malicious user could potentially corrupt or even delete your entire database. You should learn how to use parameters immediately and use them all the time. [Here](https://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my take on how to do that, but you can find plenty of other information on the subject as well.

Comment: You should also start using sensible names for EVERYTHING. The names of your controls mean nothing to anyone, including yourself, so they make your code harder to read. It makes it harder for us to help you but it also makes it harder for you. I guarantee that, if you put that code down for a month or even a week and then pick it up again, you'll have little idea what control is for what purpose and you'll have to spend time working it out. If you use descriptive names then the code is self-documenting. Unless it's just for a quick test or demo, NEVER accept the default names for controls.

Comment: There's no good reason to be using a `DataSet` there. If all you are using is one `DataTable`, just use a `DataTable`. Generally speaking, you only need to create a `DataSet` if you're going to populate multiple `DataTables` within it.

Comment: Finally, while testing the number of rows in the `DataTable` is not wrong, you don't need to do so. The `Fill` method you're calling returns the number of rows it retrieved. Instead of ignoring that and getting that number elsewhere, use the number you already have.

Comment: One more point: there's no need or point to calling `Close` on your connection object. The `Fill` and `Update` methods of a data adapter leave the connection in the same state they found it. If the connection is initially closed, they will open it, use it and then close it again. If it's already open, they will use it and leave it open. You're not explicitly opening your connection so there's no point in explicitly closing it. When using data adapters, you should explicitly open the connection if and only if you are performing multiple operations.

Comment: Note that, as specified in the answer, your issue is that you have included single-quotes on a value that you shouldn't have. You only have to use single-quotes with literal text values so, if you were using parameters, this is one of the issues that would just go away. If you never have to use single-quotes, you can't use them where you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Since the ID is a number and not a string, you should remove the quotation marks.

```
consulta = "select *from QAtracker where ID=" &  val(TextBox55.Text)
```

Please note that your code is not secure against SQL injection. While the val() function works well when searching for numbers, it always outputs a number. However, exercise caution when dealing with strings, as you need to escape special characters to enhance security.

Comment: One drawback with `Val` is that it may return a number other than that intended by the user without notification. It's arguable whether that's better or worse than an unhandled exception. In this case, probably not, but it may be in some cases because it might save incorrect data. I realise that you have just addressed the immediate issue here and there are other problems with the code, but I'd suggest that using `Integer.TryParse` is still highly advisable here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the textbox returns text and SQL is text, there is no need to cast the textbox to a numeric which then will be casted to text.

However, the input should be validated to hold a number, thus - at least - use something like this:

```vb
If ComboBox2.Text <> " " And Val(TextBox55.Text) <> 0 Then 
    consulta = "select * from QAtracker where ID = " & TextBox55.Text
```

Also, do use meaningful names for the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of the ID in the database.

In your query statement, you use the '" "' structure, which treats your TextBox55.Text parameter as a string and gets an error if it doesn't match your ID data type.

You need a proper data type conversion to avoid this error.